# JQuery Mobile CSS for dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Here is a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7jknnn2n/

HTML:

```
<select class="base-choice">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>

<label class="contrastText" for="user_natives_language">Native Language</label>
<select class="first-choice" id="user_natives_language" name="user[natives_language]">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>

<label class="contrastText" for="user_next_language">I Want To Learn</label>
<select class="second-choice" id="user_next_language" name="user[next_language]">
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var $secondOption = $('.base-choice>option').clone();

$(".first-choice").change(function () {
    var userSelected = $(this).val();

    $('.second-choice').html($secondOption);


    $('.second-choice option[value="' + userSelected + '"').remove()
});
```

CSS:

```
.base-choice{
    display:none !important;
}
```

What I would like to do with the above JSFiddle is make it such that the .base-choice dropdown selector is hidden completely from the results portion of the fiddle. Also, when I toggle the Native Language dropdown and select something different you can see that the option for the I want to learn dropdown is no longer bolded. Any thoughts on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/7avurszn/1

```js
var $secondOption = $('.base-choice>option').clone();
 
$(".first-choice").change(function () {
    var userSelected = $(this).val();

    $('.second-choice').html($secondOption);


    $('.second-choice option[value="' + userSelected + '"').remove()
});
```

```css
#select-3-button {
    display:none!important;
    padding:0!important;
    opacity:0!important!;
}

.first-choice, .second-choice{opacity:.5; font-weight:normal;}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
<select class="base-choice">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>

<label class="contrastText" for="user_natives_language">Native Language</label>
<select class="first-choice" id="user_natives_language" name="user[natives_language]">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>

<label class="contrastText" for="user_next_language">I Want To Learn</label>
<select class="second-choice" id="user_next_language" name="user[next_language]">
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>
```

Comment: note the !important is important :) when working with jquery mobile

Comment: Thanks Rachel! While the JSFiddle works I'm still having issues with the #select-3-button removing the dropdown box in my development environment. Any thoughts as to why this might be?

Comment: surrounding the html in a div tag with the id of #select-3-button worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no way in CSS to select parent element you must use javascript.
In this updated fiddle I just found the select with base-choice and set the parent element (surrounding div) to also display:none.

```
$(".base-choice").parent().addClass("invisible");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7jknnn2n/4/